# Why there is no edit, delete button for this question on SO

Tags: support, stack-overflow

this is question

[Does IE8 have rendering bugs like 6 or 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695347/does-ie8-have-rendering-bugs-like-6-or-7-closed)

Comment: Question reopened.

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan Sampson IMO SO is the best place for this question why it had moved to SU. it was related to browser rendering. Thanks for opening

Answer (score 2):

Migrated questions are (equivalent to being) locked, you need to edit at the other site.

https://superuser.com/questions/67705/does-ie8-have-rendering-bugs-like-6-or-7

Comment: if i edit can it got back to SO

Comment: the changes made in the migrated post on superuser does not reflect on SO, but the question is now back to SO